# how to update deadline date for a specific task

Tags: java

I've got 2 classes: Deadline and Task. Within the Task class, I want to create an extendDeadline method where it increases the deadline of a task. I tried the following:

```
public void extendDeadline(int extend){

    deadline = deadline + extend;
}
```

but this didn't work because the type of deadline is Deadline. Can anyone help me?

Code for deadline class:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class Deadline {
    // dates are stored as the number of seconds since 01/01/1970
    private long deadline;
    // we have a DateFormat to format the date as text
    private DateFormat dateFormatter;

    // define some constants...
public static final long SECOND = 1000;
public static final long MINUTE = SECOND*60;
public static final long HOUR = MINUTE * 60;
public static final long DAY = HOUR*24;
public static final long WEEK = DAY*7;

/**
 * Construct a new deadline.  
 * By default, deadlines are one week ahead of the time now.
 */
public Deadline() {
    // by default you get a week
    deadline = now() + WEEK;
    dateFormatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
}

/**
 * @return the time now as a long
 */
private long now() {
    return new Date().getTime();
}

/**
 * Get the date of this deadline as a Date object.
 * @return the date of this deadline as a Date object.
 */
private Date getDeadlineDate() {
    return new Date(deadline);
}

/**
 * Change the date of this deadline by a specified number of days.
 * @param numDays the number of days to add to the deadline date (may be negative).
 */
public void setNewDeadline(int numDays) {
    deadline = deadline + (DAY*numDays);
}

/**
 * Find out if this deadline has passed.
 * @return true when the time now is later than the deadline.
 */
public boolean hasPassed() {
    return now() > deadline;
}

/**
 * Return this deadline formatted as text to be printed.
 * @return a string representation of this deadline.
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return dateFormatter.format(getDeadlineDate());
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Deadline) {
        Deadline other = (Deadline) o;
        if (this.toString().equals(other.toString())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

code for task class:

```
public class Task {
private int id;
private String description;
private Deadline deadline;
private boolean done;
private int estimatedLength;
private int hoursWork;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Task
 */
public Task(int id , String description, int estimatedLength) {
    this.description = description;
    this.id = id;
    this.estimatedLength = estimatedLength;
    deadline = new Deadline();
    done = false;
    hoursWork = hoursWork;

}

public int getId(){
    return id;
}

public Deadline getDeadline(){
    return deadline;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}

public boolean isDone(){
    return done;
}

public double getPercentageComplete(){ //make sure this is right
    double result = 0;
    double hoursWorkDouble = (double) hoursWork;
    double estimatedLengthDouble = (double) estimatedLength;
    result = (double) hoursWork / (double) estimatedLength * 100.0;
    System.out.println("Percentage complete: "+result);
    return result;

}

public boolean isLate(){
    if(done = false) { // dont forget to put AND date greater deadline
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }

}

public void setDone(){
    this.done = true;
}

public void extendEstimate(int extendEstimate){
    estimatedLength = estimatedLength + extendEstimate;

    /*int extendEstimate= 0;
    int estimatedLength= 0;
    int result= extendEstimate + estimatedLength;
    System.out.println(+result);
     */

}

public void recordHoursWorked(int recordHours){
    hoursWork= hoursWork + recordHours;

}

public void extendDeadline(int extend){

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an `setNewDeadline(int numDays)` method in your Deadline class. (this should probably be renamed to something like `extendDeadlineByDays` because you're not resetting the deadline, just extending it) It looks like what you actually want to do is call that method. So, in the Task class, the method should look like this:

```
public void extendDeadline(int extend){
    deadline.setNewDeadline(extend);
}
```

In this case you're updating the deadline, rather than trying to reassign it. What you were trying to do was take a Deadline, and add an int to it, which is impossible.